# Correct dependency array for useEffect with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using [Create-React-App](https://create-react-app.dev/) and the (excellent) [use-http](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-http) for a custom useFetch hook. The goal is to make several API calls upon login to an account area:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null)
const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)

const request = useFetch('/')

const initializeAccount = async () => {
  try {
    const user = await request.get('api/user/')
    const profile = await request.get('api/profile/')
    const posts = await request.get('api/posts/')
    if (user) {
      setUser(user.data)
    }
    if (profile) {
      setProfile(profile.data)
    }
    if (posts) {
      setPosts(posts.data)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('could not initialize account')
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  initializeAccount()
  return () => console.log('unmount')
})
```

I have tried using `[]` as the dependency array, but I get a linting error saying to move `initializeAccount` to the dependency array. If I add it, the function runs endlessly.

What is the correct way to setup the dependency array so that this function is called one time? Also, what would be the correct way to handle abort of each of the API calls in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure if useFetch will return same reference every time but you could try the following: `const initializeAccount = useCallback(async () => {,,,},[request]);` And pass `initializeAccount` to the useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My man, in order to run useEffect once for api calls, you have to do it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   initializeAccount()
   return () => console.log('unmount')
},[])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I do this I get a linting error saying to add the dependency to the array - does that mean the linting error is incorrect? Also, what would I return in `useEffect` to abort the fetch calls?

Comment: @Toby, that is in the [documentation](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-http) `request.abort()`

Comment: @HMR I had read that, but I wasn't sure exactly how to us it - I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: @Toby that lint rule is still fairly new, and very blunt, just add a lint override for the line. I also recommend leaving a comment above that as for the reason for the override, only firing hook on mount is a pretty legit reason. I believe the authors of the react-hooks eslinter are looking into more fine-grained control/rules, may just need to wait a while.

Comment: @DrewReese I wondered if that was the case, since the empty dependency array *does* work - but I didn't want to ignore and cause an issue down the line. Thanks!

Comment: That is why I added the bit about leaving a comment. I pushed hooks hard on my team at work, then later found the hook linter, so not only had to teach team about proper hook usage, but then also proper lint rule management. It can get messy with auto-formatters that also try to automagically fix lint warnings as well, which is the reason overrides are needed and the comment helps explain to fellow devs *why* the override, that is definitely on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The lint error is there for a reason and ignoring it might cause bugs that are very hard to find.

#### No dependency array

If you exclude the dependency array completely (`useEffect(() => { /* ... */ });`) the effect will run on every render, causing an infinite loop.

#### Empty dependency array

If you add an empty dependency array (`useEffect(() => { /* ... */ }, [])`) the effect will only run on first render. That might work here but it will cause issues in other scenarios, or if something change in the future. E.g. say that `request` takes some time to initialize (so it's first `undefined`, to later change to an object) and that `initializeAccount` looks like below. Now `initalizeAccount` would run only on first render with `request === undefined`, when `request` is ready in a later stage and the component is re-rendered, `initalizeAccount` won't run again and the functionality will silently fail.

```js
const initializeAccount = async () => {
  if (request) {
    const user = await request.get('api/user/')
    if (user) {
      setUser(user.data)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Populated dependency array (the right way)

If you add `initializeAccount` to the dependency array (`useEffect(() => { /*...*/ }, [initalizeAccount])`) the effect will run every time `initializeAccount` is changed. For objects (and functions) React compares the *reference* from the last render with the reference from the current render to determine if the object has changed. The way you define `initializeAccount` it will be redefined on every render and hence the reference will be new and the effect will run on every render, just as you experience.

What you need to do is to obtain a stable reference to `initalizeAccount`. For this React provides [`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback), it is similar to `useEffect` in that it has a dependency array. If we define `initializeAccount` with `useCallback`, React will make sure that the reference is the same between renders. It is only when one of the dependencies in the dependency array of `useCallback` change that the function is redefined which in turn triggers the `useEffect` to run again. This way you are adhering to the lint rule while at the same time the effect is only run once.

```js
const initializeAccount = useCallback(async () => {
  if (request) {
    const user = await request.get('api/user/')
    if (user) {
      setUser(user.data)
    }
  }
}, [request])
```

Note that if `request`, in turn, doesn't have a stable reference, `useCallback` will be run on each render (as described above) and then so will `useEffect`. If `useFetch` is written by you, make sure it returns an object with a stable reference. If `useFetch` is provided from a library, that is most likely the case already.

#### TL;DR

Wrap `initializeAccount` in `useCallback` and add it to the dependency array of `useEffect`.

```js
const initializeAccount = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const user = await request.get('api/user/')
    const profile = await request.get('api/profile/')
    const posts = await request.get('api/posts/')
    if (user) {
      setUser(user.data)
    }
    if (profile) {
      setProfile(profile.data)
    }
    if (posts) {
      setPosts(posts.data)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('could not initialize account')
  }
}, [request])

useEffect(() => {
  initializeAccount()
  return () => console.log('unmount')
}, [initializeAccount])
```